# Rails - Unique Array in View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, unique

Having a Bit of trouble displaying unique results from my database. I have a database called "Activities". Each Activity has an associated Sport through sport_id. There may be many activities with the same sport_id.

I want to display  a list of all sports linked to the activities database without displaying (for example "Football") twice.

FYI : **Venues** have many **Facilities** and **Facilities** have many **Activities**.

Controller:

```
@sports = Sport.all
@activities = Activity.paginate(page: params[:page])
@facilities = Facility.where(venue_id: @venue.id)
```

View:

```
<% @facilities.each do |f| %>
  <% @activities.find(:all, :conditions => "facility_id == #{f.id} ").each do |a| %>
   <li><%= Sport.find(a.sport_id).name %>, (<%= a.facility_id %>)</li>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This shows:

- Football, (2)
- Hockey, (2)
- Hockey, (2)
- Football, (5)

I would like to display just:

- Football
- Hockey

Any ideas?

Comment: why not add a distinct condition in your request? what is unclear is that the different "hockey" element, are they part of different facilities or the same one?

Comment: Hi @tomsoft I have edited the questions to show the facility id in brackets. It shows that there are 3 activities in facility ID 3 and 1 activity in facility ID 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution would be to reduce your array with ruby in the view using: [uniq!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-uniq-21)

```
<% @facilities.each do |f| %>
  <% @activities.find(:all, :conditions => "facility_id == #{f.id} ").uniq! { |a| a.sport_id }.each do |a| %>
    <li><%= link_to Sport.find(a.sport_id).name, Sport.find(a.sport_id) %></li>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Another way may be to perform a single query on your DB since Sport what you want to narrow down

In controller:

```
@sports = Sport.joins(activities: [facility: :venue]).where(facilities: { venue_id: @venue.id }).distinct
```

In view:

```
<% @sports.each do |sport| %>
  <li><%= link_to sport.name, sport %></li>
<% end %>
```

I am not sure about your DB schema so I went with what I thought you would have done, but it might needs some tweakings.

I hope I helped you.

Comment: Second way with the sports worked a treat! Thank you very much. I need to research further into "Joins". Thank you @Voxdei !

Answer (score 0):

try to use [reject](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/reject) before each

```
<% @facilities.reject{your condition here}.each do |f| %>
```